# Support for the `darken` function in Dart Sass

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, wordpress-gutenberg, dart-sass

In one of the SCSS stylesheets in our project, we import two stylesheets from the WordPress Gutenberg components

```scss
@import '@gutenberg-components/button/style.scss';
@import '@gutenberg-components/date-time/style.scss';
```

(`@gutenberg-components` is an alias for `./node_modules/@wordpress/components/src`).

These stylesheets use the Sass function `darken` for some colors. This is fine when we build our CSS using LibSass. But when we use Dart Sass instead, we get this error:

```
SassError: This function isn't allowed in plain CSS.
        ╷
    152 │   color: darken(#cacccd,10%);
```

The Sass [docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#darken) say something ambiguous about `darken`.

> Because `darken()` is usually not the best way to make a color darker, it’s not included directly in the new module system. However, if you have to preserve the existing behavior, `darken($color, $amount)` can be written `color.adjust($color, $lightness: -$amount)`.

I understand this to mean Dart Sass won't transpile `darken` properly, and you need to replace it with `color.adjust` if you're using Dart Sass. Is that correct?

Another confusing thing is that [Gutenberg](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg) already seems to be using Dart Sass. Yet they apparently don't get this error in their project, because they're still using `darken`. How do they make it work for them?